# Image not cropping to corner in imageview

Tags: android, imageview

I used drawable xml to set background of imageView

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="20dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@color/light_gray"/>
            <size android:height="210dp" android:width="210dp"/>
        </shape>
        <clip>
        </clip>
    </item>
</selector>
```

then i tried to set image to image view it gives me image like this

code of imageView

```
 <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sent_image"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/imageview"
                android:padding="0dp"
                />
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7Byd.png

Then i gave padding to image view it gives
me image like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkDTB.png

[I want image to look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzxZi.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use This class as your `ImageView`

**SelectableRoundedImageView.java**

```
public class SelectableRoundedImageView extends ImageView {

public static final String TAG = "SelectableRoundedImageView";

private int mResource = 0;

private static final ScaleType[] sScaleTypeArray = { ScaleType.MATRIX,
        ScaleType.FIT_XY, ScaleType.FIT_START, ScaleType.FIT_CENTER,
        ScaleType.FIT_END, ScaleType.CENTER, ScaleType.CENTER_CROP,
        ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE };

// Set default scale type to FIT_CENTER, which is default scale type of
// original ImageView.
private ScaleType mScaleType = ScaleType.FIT_CENTER;

private float mLeftTopCornerRadius = 0.0f;
private float mRightTopCornerRadius = 0.0f;
private float mLeftBottomCornerRadius = 0.0f;
private float mRightBottomCornerRadius = 0.0f;

private float mBorderWidth = 0.0f;
private static final int DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR = Color.BLACK;
private ColorStateList mBorderColor = ColorStateList
        .valueOf(DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR);

private boolean isOval = false;

private Drawable mDrawable;

private float[] mRadii = new float[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

public SelectableRoundedImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public SelectableRoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public SelectableRoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
        int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
            R.styleable.SelectableRoundedImageView, defStyle, 0);

    final int index = a.getInt(
            R.styleable.SelectableRoundedImageView_android_scaleType, -1);
    if (index >= 0) {
        setScaleType(sScaleTypeArray[index]);
    }

    mLeftTopCornerRadius = a
            .getDimensionPixelSize(
                    R.styleable.SelectableRoundedImageView_sriv_left_top_corner_radius,
                    0);
    mRightTopCornerRadius = a
            .getDimensionPixelSize(
                    R.styleable.SelectableRoundedImageView_sriv_right_top_corner_radius,
                    0);
    mLeftBottomCornerRadius = a
            .getDimensionPixelSize(
                    R.styleable.SelectableRoundedImageView_sriv_left_bottom_corner_radius,
                    0);
    mRightBottomCornerRadius = a
            .getDimensionPixelSize(
                    R.styleable.SelectableRoundedImageView_sriv_right_bottom_corner_radius,
                    0);

    if (mLeftTopCornerRadius < 0.0f || mRightTopCornerRadius < 0.0f
            || mLeftBottomCornerRadius < 0.0f
            || mRightBottomCornerRadius < 0.0f) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "radius values cannot be negative.");
    }

    mRadii = new float[] { mLeftTopCornerRadius, mLeftTopCornerRadius,
            mRightTopCornerRadius, mRightTopCornerRadius,
            mRightBottomCornerRadius, mRightBottomCornerRadius,
            mLeftBottomCornerRadius, mLeftBottomCornerRadius };

    mBorderWidth = a.getDimensionPixelSize(
            R.styleable.SelectableRoundedImageView_sriv_border_width, 0);
    if (mBorderWidth < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "border width cannot be negative.");
    }

    mBorderColor = a
            .getColorStateList(R.styleable.SelectableRoundedImageView_sriv_border_color);
    if (mBorderColor == null) {
        mBorderColor = ColorStateList.valueOf(DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR);
    }

    isOval = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.SelectableRoundedImageView_sriv_oval,
            false);
    a.recycle();

    updateDrawable();
}

@Override
protected void drawableStateChanged() {
    super.drawableStateChanged();
    invalidate();
}

@Override
public ScaleType getScaleType() {
    return mScaleType;
}

@Override
public void setScaleType(ScaleType scaleType) {
    super.setScaleType(scaleType);
    mScaleType = scaleType;
    updateDrawable();
}

@Override
public void setImageDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
    mResource = 0;
    mDrawable = SelectableRoundedCornerDrawable.fromDrawable(drawable,
            getResources());
    super.setImageDrawable(mDrawable);
    updateDrawable();
}

@Override
public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm) {
    mResource = 0;
    mDrawable = SelectableRoundedCornerDrawable.fromBitmap(bm,
            getResources());
    super.setImageDrawable(mDrawable);
    updateDrawable();
}

@Override
public void setImageResource(int resId) {
    if (mResource != resId) {
        mResource = resId;
        mDrawable = resolveResource();
        super.setImageDrawable(mDrawable);
        updateDrawable();
    }
}

@Override
public void setImageURI(Uri uri) {
    super.setImageURI(uri);
    setImageDrawable(getDrawable());
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private Drawable resolveResource() {
    Resources rsrc = getResources();
    if (rsrc == null) {
        return null;
    }

    Drawable d = null;

    if (mResource != 0) {
        try {
            d = rsrc.getDrawable(mResource);
        } catch (NotFoundException e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Unable to find resource: " + mResource, e);
            // Don't try again.
            mResource = 0;
        }
    }
    return SelectableRoundedCornerDrawable.fromDrawable(d, getResources());
}

private void updateDrawable() {
    if (mDrawable == null) {
        return;
    }

    ((SelectableRoundedCornerDrawable) mDrawable).setScaleType(mScaleType);
    ((SelectableRoundedCornerDrawable) mDrawable).setCornerRadii(mRadii);
    ((SelectableRoundedCornerDrawable) mDrawable)
            .setBorderWidth(mBorderWidth);
    ((SelectableRoundedCornerDrawable) mDrawable)
            .setBorderColor(mBorderColor);
    ((SelectableRoundedCornerDrawable) mDrawable).setOval(isOval);
}

public float getCornerRadius() {
    return mLeftTopCornerRadius;
}

/**
 * Set radii for each corner.
 * 
 * @param leftTop
 *            The desired radius for left-top corner in dip.
 * @param rightTop
 *            The desired desired radius for right-top corner in dip.
 * @param leftBottom
 *            The desired radius for left-bottom corner in dip.
 * @param rightBottom
 *            The desired radius for right-bottom corner in dip.
 * 
 */
public void setCornerRadiiDP(float leftTop, float rightTop,
        float leftBottom, float rightBottom) {
    final float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

    final float lt = leftTop * density;
    final float rt = rightTop * density;
    final float lb = leftBottom * density;
    final float rb = rightBottom * density;

    mRadii = new float[] { lt, lt, rt, rt, rb, rb, lb, lb };
    updateDrawable();
}

public float getBorderWidth() {
    return mBorderWidth;
}

/**
 * Set border width.
 * 
 * @param width
 *            The desired width in dip.
 */
public void setBorderWidthDP(float width) {
    float scaledWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density * width;
    if (mBorderWidth == scaledWidth) {
        return;
    }

    mBorderWidth = scaledWidth;
    updateDrawable();
    invalidate();
}

public int getBorderColor() {
    return mBorderColor.getDefaultColor();
}

public void setBorderColor(int color) {
    setBorderColor(ColorStateList.valueOf(color));
}

public ColorStateList getBorderColors() {
    return mBorderColor;
}

public void setBorderColor(ColorStateList colors) {
    if (mBorderColor.equals(colors)) {
        return;
    }

    mBorderColor = (colors != null) ? colors : ColorStateList
            .valueOf(DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR);
    updateDrawable();
    if (mBorderWidth > 0) {
        invalidate();
    }
}

public boolean isOval() {
    return isOval;
}

public void setOval(boolean oval) {
    isOval = oval;
    updateDrawable();
    invalidate();
}

static class SelectableRoundedCornerDrawable extends Drawable {

    private static final String TAG = "SelectableRoundedCornerDrawable";
    private static final int DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR = Color.BLACK;

    private RectF mBounds = new RectF();
    private RectF mBorderBounds = new RectF();

    private final RectF mBitmapRect = new RectF();
    private final int mBitmapWidth;
    private final int mBitmapHeight;

    private final Paint mBitmapPaint;
    private final Paint mBorderPaint;

    private BitmapShader mBitmapShader;

    private float[] mRadii = new float[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    private float[] mBorderRadii = new float[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

    private boolean mOval = false;

    private float mBorderWidth = 0;
    private ColorStateList mBorderColor = ColorStateList
            .valueOf(DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR);
    // Set default scale type to FIT_CENTER, which is default scale type of
    // original ImageView.
    private ScaleType mScaleType = ScaleType.FIT_CENTER;

    private Path mPath = new Path();
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private boolean mBoundsConfigured = false;

    public SelectableRoundedCornerDrawable(Bitmap bitmap, Resources r) {
        mBitmap = bitmap;
        mBitmapShader = new BitmapShader(bitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP,
                Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);

        if (bitmap != null) {
            mBitmapWidth = bitmap.getScaledWidth(r.getDisplayMetrics());
            mBitmapHeight = bitmap.getScaledHeight(r.getDisplayMetrics());
        } else {
            mBitmapWidth = mBitmapHeight = -1;
        }

        mBitmapRect.set(0, 0, mBitmapWidth, mBitmapHeight);

        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mBitmapPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mBitmapPaint.setShader(mBitmapShader);

        mBorderPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mBorderPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mBorderPaint.setColor(mBorderColor.getColorForState(getState(),
                DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR));
        mBorderPaint.setStrokeWidth(mBorderWidth);
    }

    public static SelectableRoundedCornerDrawable fromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap,
            Resources r) {
        if (bitmap != null) {
            return new SelectableRoundedCornerDrawable(bitmap, r);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static Drawable fromDrawable(Drawable drawable, Resources r) {
        if (drawable != null) {
            if (drawable instanceof SelectableRoundedCornerDrawable) {
                return drawable;
            } else if (drawable instanceof LayerDrawable) {
                LayerDrawable ld = (LayerDrawable) drawable;
                final int num = ld.getNumberOfLayers();
                for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
                    Drawable d = ld.getDrawable(i);
                    ld.setDrawableByLayerId(ld.getId(i), fromDrawable(d, r));
                }
                return ld;
            }

            Bitmap bm = drawableToBitmap(drawable);
            if (bm != null) {
                return new SelectableRoundedCornerDrawable(bm, r);
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "Failed to create bitmap from drawable!");
            }
        }
        return drawable;
    }

    public static Bitmap drawableToBitmap(Drawable drawable) {
        if (drawable == null) {
            return null;
        }

        if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            return ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
        }

        Bitmap bitmap;
        int width = Math.max(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), 2);
        int height = Math.max(drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), 2);
        try {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
            drawable.draw(canvas);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            bitmap = null;
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isStateful() {
        return mBorderColor.isStateful();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onStateChange(int[] state) {
        int newColor = mBorderColor.getColorForState(state, 0);
        if (mBorderPaint.getColor() != newColor) {
            mBorderPaint.setColor(newColor);
            return true;
        } else {
            return super.onStateChange(state);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void configureBounds(Canvas canvas) {
        Rect clipBounds = canvas.getClipBounds();
        Matrix canvasMatrix = canvas.getMatrix();

        if (ScaleType.CENTER == mScaleType) {
            mBounds.set(clipBounds);
        } else if (ScaleType.CENTER_CROP == mScaleType) {
            applyScaleToRadii(canvasMatrix);
            mBounds.set(clipBounds);
        } else if (ScaleType.FIT_XY == mScaleType) {
            Matrix m = new Matrix();
            m.setRectToRect(mBitmapRect, new RectF(clipBounds),
                    Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);
            mBitmapShader.setLocalMatrix(m);
            mBounds.set(clipBounds);
        } else if (ScaleType.FIT_START == mScaleType
                || ScaleType.FIT_END == mScaleType
                || ScaleType.FIT_CENTER == mScaleType
                || ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE == mScaleType) {
            applyScaleToRadii(canvasMatrix);
            mBounds.set(mBitmapRect);
        } else if (ScaleType.MATRIX == mScaleType) {
            applyScaleToRadii(canvasMatrix);
            mBounds.set(mBitmapRect);
        }
    }

    private void applyScaleToRadii(Matrix m) {
        float[] values = new float[9];
        m.getValues(values);
        for (int i = 0; i < mRadii.length; i++) {
            mRadii[i] = mRadii[i] / values[0];
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void adjustCanvasForBorder(Canvas canvas) {
        Matrix canvasMatrix = canvas.getMatrix();
        final float[] values = new float[9];
        canvasMatrix.getValues(values);

        final float scaleFactorX = values[0];
        final float scaleFactorY = values[4];
        final float translateX = values[2];
        final float translateY = values[5];

        final float newScaleX = mBounds.width()
                / (mBounds.width() + mBorderWidth + mBorderWidth);
        final float newScaleY = mBounds.height()
                / (mBounds.height() + mBorderWidth + mBorderWidth);

        canvas.scale(newScaleX, newScaleY);
        if (ScaleType.FIT_START == mScaleType
                || ScaleType.FIT_END == mScaleType
                || ScaleType.FIT_XY == mScaleType
                || ScaleType.FIT_CENTER == mScaleType
                || ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE == mScaleType
                || ScaleType.MATRIX == mScaleType) {
            canvas.translate(mBorderWidth, mBorderWidth);
        } else if (ScaleType.CENTER == mScaleType
                || ScaleType.CENTER_CROP == mScaleType) {
            // First, make translate values to 0
            canvas.translate(-translateX / (newScaleX * scaleFactorX),
                    -translateY / (newScaleY * scaleFactorY));
            // Then, set the final translate values.
            canvas.translate(-(mBounds.left - mBorderWidth),
                    -(mBounds.top - mBorderWidth));
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void adjustBorderWidthAndBorderBounds(Canvas canvas) {
        Matrix canvasMatrix = canvas.getMatrix();
        final float[] values = new float[9];
        canvasMatrix.getValues(values);

        final float scaleFactor = values[0];

        float viewWidth = mBounds.width() * scaleFactor;
        mBorderWidth = (mBorderWidth * mBounds.width())
                / (viewWidth - (2 * mBorderWidth));
        mBorderPaint.setStrokeWidth(mBorderWidth);

        mBorderBounds.set(mBounds);
        mBorderBounds.inset(-mBorderWidth / 2, -mBorderWidth / 2);
    }

    private void setBorderRadii() {
        for (int i = 0; i < mRadii.length; i++) {
            if (mRadii[i] > 0) {
                mBorderRadii[i] = mRadii[i];
                mRadii[i] = mRadii[i] - mBorderWidth;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.save();
        if (!mBoundsConfigured) {
            configureBounds(canvas);
            if (mBorderWidth > 0) {
                adjustBorderWidthAndBorderBounds(canvas);
                setBorderRadii();
            }
            mBoundsConfigured = true;
        }

        if (mOval) {
            if (mBorderWidth > 0) {
                adjustCanvasForBorder(canvas);
                mPath.addOval(mBounds, Path.Direction.CW);
                canvas.drawPath(mPath, mBitmapPaint);
                mPath.reset();
                mPath.addOval(mBorderBounds, Path.Direction.CW);
                canvas.drawPath(mPath, mBorderPaint);
            } else {
                mPath.addOval(mBounds, Path.Direction.CW);
                canvas.drawPath(mPath, mBitmapPaint);
            }
        } else {
            if (mBorderWidth > 0) {
                adjustCanvasForBorder(canvas);
                mPath.addRoundRect(mBounds, mRadii, Path.Direction.CW);
                canvas.drawPath(mPath, mBitmapPaint);
                mPath.reset();
                mPath.addRoundRect(mBorderBounds, mBorderRadii,
                        Path.Direction.CW);
                canvas.drawPath(mPath, mBorderPaint);
            } else {
                mPath.addRoundRect(mBounds, mRadii, Path.Direction.CW);
                canvas.drawPath(mPath, mBitmapPaint);
            }
        }
        canvas.restore();
    }

    public void setCornerRadii(float[] radii) {
        if (radii == null)
            return;

        if (radii.length != 8) {
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(
                    "radii[] needs 8 values");
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < radii.length; i++) {
            mRadii[i] = radii[i];
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return (mBitmap == null || mBitmap.hasAlpha() || mBitmapPaint
                .getAlpha() < 255) ? PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
                : PixelFormat.OPAQUE;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
        mBitmapPaint.setAlpha(alpha);
        invalidateSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
        mBitmapPaint.setColorFilter(cf);
        invalidateSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public void setDither(boolean dither) {
        mBitmapPaint.setDither(dither);
        invalidateSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public void setFilterBitmap(boolean filter) {
        mBitmapPaint.setFilterBitmap(filter);
        invalidateSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public int getIntrinsicWidth() {
        return mBitmapWidth;
    }

    @Override
    public int getIntrinsicHeight() {
        return mBitmapHeight;
    }

    public float getBorderWidth() {
        return mBorderWidth;
    }

    public void setBorderWidth(float width) {
        mBorderWidth = width;
        mBorderPaint.setStrokeWidth(width);
    }

    public int getBorderColor() {
        return mBorderColor.getDefaultColor();
    }

    public void setBorderColor(int color) {
        setBorderColor(ColorStateList.valueOf(color));
    }

    public ColorStateList getBorderColors() {
        return mBorderColor;
    }

    /**
     * Controls border color of this ImageView.
     * 
     * @param colors
     *            The desired border color. If it's null, no border will be
     *            drawn.
     * 
     */
    public void setBorderColor(ColorStateList colors) {
        if (colors == null) {
            mBorderWidth = 0;
            mBorderColor = ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            mBorderPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        } else {
            mBorderColor = colors;
            mBorderPaint.setColor(mBorderColor.getColorForState(getState(),
                    DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR));
        }
    }

    public boolean isOval() {
        return mOval;
    }

    public void setOval(boolean oval) {
        mOval = oval;
    }

    public ScaleType getScaleType() {
        return mScaleType;
    }

    public void setScaleType(ScaleType scaleType) {
        if (scaleType == null) {
            return;
        }
        mScaleType = scaleType;
    }
}
}
```

You Need This `attars`

**attars.xml**

```
<resources>

<declare-styleable name="SelectableRoundedImageView">
    <attr name="sriv_left_top_corner_radius" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="sriv_right_top_corner_radius" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="sriv_left_bottom_corner_radius" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="sriv_right_bottom_corner_radius" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="sriv_border_width" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="sriv_border_color" format="color" />
    <attr name="sriv_oval" format="boolean" />
    <attr name="android:scaleType" />
</declare-styleable>
```

And You can use it like this.

```
  <vrund.purohit.mylibrary.extraclasses.SelectableRoundedImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivCover"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/hp1"
        app:sriv_left_bottom_corner_radius="3dip"
        app:sriv_left_top_corner_radius="3dip"
        app:sriv_right_bottom_corner_radius="3dip"
        app:sriv_right_top_corner_radius=3dip" />
```

Hope this will help you out.

Comment: Thanks, works pretty damn fine. But there is one problem, sometimes the images are too small, any way to set the mimimum size of the imageview?

Comment: you can add attribute `android:scaleType="fitXY"` or `            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
`.

Comment: i tried sending multiple images of diff sizes so i got this   http://i.imgur.com/lTEG1pg.png  i want all images to be of same size

Comment: are you setting hight and width of Imageview To fix size?

Comment: <com.imate.custom.SelectableRoundedImageView
                android:id="@+id/sent_image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:sriv_left_bottom_corner_radius="10dip"
                app:sriv_left_top_corner_radius="10dip"
                app:sriv_right_bottom_corner_radius="10dip"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:sriv_right_top_corner_radius="10dip" />

Comment: You see you are giving hight and width to wrap_content. now it will display according to Image's hight and width. Try to give both in fix density pixels like 120dpx90dp or whatever you want. if want to set Minimum width of ImageView you can also add ` android:minWidth="120dp"`. and same for hight.

Comment: I am Glad to hear that.

Comment: would you like to move to mumbai and work in my company?

Comment: app development company

Comment: sure.. can you please send me your company details?

Comment: give me u r email address